# How to write custom regular expression

Tags: asp.net, regex

I Would like to write a custom regular expression where the format is like XYZ-ABC-001 
where

1. XYZ is fixed,
2. ABC is variable (it can be any three characters between A-Z )
3. 001 is variable (it can be any number between 0-9)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will match:

`XYZ-[a-zA-Z]{3}-\d+`

Comment: This regex allows for an arbitrary number of digits in the last group. I agree that the question is not absolutely clear at this point, but if it is a requirement to have exactly three digits, then `\d+` should be replaced by `\d{3}`, if it can be enything between one and three digits, then `\d{1,3}` will fit. +1, anyway.

Comment: You are right Patrick, The lenght of digit must be three . So just i modified expression provided by TechnoCare as per my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

DIY kit: http://txt2re.com/

Example: http://txt2re.com/index-csharp.php3?s=XYZ-ABC-001&4&22&23&24&-17&-18&14&15&16

Results in the C# output:

```
   string txt="XYZ-ABC-001";
```

```
  string re1="((?:[a-z][a-z]+))";   // Word 1
  string re2="(-)"; // Any Single Character 1
  string re3="(.)"; // Any Single Character 2
  string re4="(.)"; // Any Single Character 3
  string re5="(.)"; // Any Single Character 4
  string re6="(-)"; // Any Single Character 5
  string re7="(\\d)";   // Any Single Digit 1
  string re8="(\\d)";   // Any Single Digit 2
  string re9="(\\d)";   // Any Single Digit 3

  Regex r = new Regex(re1+re2+re3+re4+re5+re6+re7+re8+re9,RegexOptions.IgnoreCase|RegexOptions.Singleline);
  Match m = r.Match(txt);
  if (m.Success)
  {
        String word1=m.Groups[1].ToString();
        String c1=m.Groups[2].ToString();
        String c2=m.Groups[3].ToString();
        String c3=m.Groups[4].ToString();
        String c4=m.Groups[5].ToString();
        String c5=m.Groups[6].ToString();
        String d1=m.Groups[7].ToString();
        String d2=m.Groups[8].ToString();
        String d3=m.Groups[9].ToString();
        Console.Write("("+word1.ToString()+")"+"("+c1.ToString()+")"+"("+c2.ToString()+")"+"("+c3.ToString()+")"+"("+c4.ToString()+")"+"("+c5.ToString()+")"+"("+d1.ToString()+")"+"("+d2.ToString()+")"+"("+d3.ToString()+")"+"\n");
  }
```

Then you can modify it slightly to adjust to your needs, for example replacing `(.)` with `([A-Z])`.

Comment: Extremely ugly, unreadable, and about 20 times longer than it should be. By that way, I could never get txt2re.com to produce the regex `a+b+`. I don't think that site has an overall positive effect.